# Unable to find all angles of a trigonometric triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. And have gotten close to slowing it but I am unsure what small mistake I am doing.

This is the question
[Here is the Question, it is in Norwegian but translated it says "In the $\triangle ABC$ $AC=8$, $\angle B=30^\circ$ and the length of the Normal $BP$ from $B$ thru the line $AC$ is $6$. Find the angles of $ABC$"[1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFieI.png

[Solution]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB3jl.png

This has been my idea so far:

$sin(30) = \frac 8x, x= 16$ such that I find the length of line CB

$$\sin(c) = \dfrac{6}{16}, x= 0.365$$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(0.366)) = 22.02$$

I don't bother to do anything more since finding the other angel will of course result in the wrong result

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Can you explain why sin (30) = 8/x? Also, what is x?

Comment: Hint: Let $ BC = x, BA = y$. What can we say about $ \sin \angle ABP$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I use 8 as the opposite side of the triangle and x as the hypotenus. And we know that angle B is 30 degrees which I used as the angle to perform the calculations.

Comment: Note that $ABC$ isn't a right triangle, so how are you applying sin 30?

Comment: @CalvinLin that is probably a problem.

But if we say that BC=x, BA=y. Could we say that the angle of B in ABP will be 180 - 30 - 90= 60?

Comment: Nope. We don't know what that angle is as yet. EG can you explain your logic/calculation, rather than just writing out numbers? $\quad$  Are you familiar with calculating $\sin (\alpha + \beta)$ or $ \sin ( \alpha - \beta)$? If so, use that here.

Comment: sorry, our teacher has not gone thru that. I belive it is because my class changed the curriculum mid thru the year. So there might be some gaps in my knowledge

Comment: I'm afraid (but not fully certain) that you don't know enough to tackle this then. It might be helpful to state how much trigo you know (esp if you're saying that sin 30 = 8/x, or not clear on what the angle sum is)

Comment: @CalvinLin I do know how to use the trigonometric functions, sine and cosine rule and a small introduction into the unit circle. I have not used these functions in a while as this task is a grade bellow and in Norway you just ignore Trig for an entire year (don't know why and found it weird at the start). But this was given to me by my teacher as a task since he could not solve it himself. I gave it a shot but as it seems I do not know enough to be able to solve this.

Could you fill me in on what I should learn to solve this

Comment: But in theory it should be possible to solve it with the tools I was given else they would not be able to put it on an exam

Comment: I would use the fact that $ \sin (\alpha -  \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta -  \cos \alpha \sin \beta$. The idea here is that if we set $ \alpha = \angle CBP, \beta = \angle ABP$, then we have the value of the LHS, and can work out the RHS in terms of the unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AP = x$.
Then $AB = \sqrt{ x^2 + 36}$ and $CB = \sqrt{ x^2 + 16x + 100 }$.

Consider angles $\angle CBP, \angle ABP$.
$\sin \angle CBP = \frac{8+x} { \sqrt{ x^2 + 16x + 100 }}, \cos \angle CBP = \frac{6}{ \sqrt{ x^2 + 16x + 100 } }$.
$\sin \angle ABP = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 36 } }, \cos \angle ABP = \frac{6}{\sqrt{x^2 + 36 } }$.

Hence, $ \frac{1}{2} = \sin 30^\circ = \sin (\angle CBP - \angle ABP) = \frac{8+x} { \sqrt{ x^2 + 16x + 100 }} \times \frac{6}{\sqrt{x^2 + 36 } } - \frac{6}{ \sqrt{ x^2 + 16x + 100 } } \times \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 36 } }$

This gives us $(x^2 + 16x + 100)(x^2 + 36) = 96^2$.
Solving the quartic polynomial for $x$, we get $ x = 2(\sqrt{ 12 \sqrt{3} - 5 } - 2 ) \approx 3.95$

Finally, $\angle BCP = \sin^{-1} \frac{ 6}{\sqrt{ x^2 + 16 x + 100 }} \approx 26.7$ as stated.

Comment: @TheOnlyTater FWIW I don't think this solution is what your teachers had in mind. Solving that quartic is painful (even though it does have a nice form), and I resorted to a calculation aid.

Answer (score 2):

If it's part of your knowledge base, considering the triangle $ABC$:

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]

to determine the variable $x > 0$ it's sufficient to impose:

$$
\overline{A-B} \cdot \overline{C-B} = ||\overline{A-B}||\;||\overline{C-B}||\cos(30°)
$$

from which:

$$
x(x+8) + 36 = \sqrt{x^2+36}\;\sqrt{(x+8)^2+36}\;\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

then squaring both sides and ordering the monomials, we get:

$$
x^{\color{red}{4}} + \color{blue}{16}\,x^3 + 136\,x^2 + 576\,x - 5616 = 0.
$$

Now, the general idea is to reduce to a depressed quartic equation of the cubic term:

$$
x = y - \frac{\color{blue}{16}}{\color{red}{4}}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
y^4 + 40\,y^2 - 6512 = 0
$$

where luck wants us to obtain a depressed quartic equation also of the linear term!

It's precisely for this fact that it turns out to be an easily solvable quartic equation:

$$
y^2 = -20+48\sqrt{3}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
x = 2\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}-4
$$

from which the required angle:

$$
\widehat{ACB} = \arctan\left(\frac{6}{x+8}\right) \approx \boxed{26.7°}\,.
$$

---

Otherwise, set $\widehat{ACB} \equiv \gamma$, applying the *law of sines* to triangles $ABC$ and $ABP$:

$$
\frac{\sin\gamma}{\overline{AB}} = \frac{\sin(30°)}{8},
\quad \quad \quad
\frac{\sin(90°)}{\overline{AB}} = \frac{\sin(\gamma+30°)}{6}
$$

from which:

$$
\frac{6}{\overline{AB}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,\sin\gamma + \frac{1}{2}\,\cos\gamma = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,\frac{\overline{AB}}{16} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\overline{AB}}{16}\right)^2}
$$

i.e

$$
\left(\frac{6}{\overline{AB}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,\frac{\overline{AB}}{16}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\overline{AB}}{16}\right)^2}\right)^2
$$

where by expanding the squares and rearranging the monomials, we get:

$$
\overline{AB}^4 - 32\left(3\sqrt{3}+2\right)\overline{AB}^2 + 9216 = 0
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\overline{AB} = 4\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{12\sqrt{3}-5}}
$$

from which the required angle:

$$
\gamma = \arcsin\left(\frac{\overline{AB}}{16}\right) \approx \boxed{26.7°}\,.
$$

While the calculations remain horrific, this is a way more befitting of a high school.